# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. flutter error android studio

Tags: android, flutter

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1121
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not create task ':app:copyFlutterAssetsDebug'.
> > Could not create task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> > Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle_core() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

how to fix this error

Comment: Please add the code that you are trying to run as well. Maybe there is an error because of that.